# How to get gRPC request when a panic occurs in Golang

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

I have a Go server defined like this in proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package go-package;

option go_package = "github.com/path/to/go-package";

import "vibe.proto";

service MyService {
  rpc Function (stream TheRequest) returns (stream TheResponse) {}
}

message TheRequest {
  oneof Payload {
    Config config = 1;
    Messages messages = 2;
  }
}

message Config {
  // config some fields here
}

message Messages {
  repeated string messages = 1;
}
```

I'm using https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware as an interceptor engine. I need to implement logging of the request or Messages when I have a panic, because right now the code is panicked, but i don't have any information about the request.

Answer (score 3):

Just add interceptor with recovery, simple example:

```
func RecoveryUnaryInterceptor(ctx context.Context, req interface{}, info *grpc.UnaryServerInfo, handler grpc.UnaryHandler) (_ interface{}, err error) {
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            err = status.Error(codes.Internal, fmt.Sprintf("Panic: `%s` %s", info.FullMethod, string(debug.Stack())))
        }
    }()
    return handler(ctx, req)
}
```

Comment: Yes, this prints the debug stack (which works and helps), but the request is in memory address format, so still I don't know the exact input that caused the panic. Any way to retrieve that information?

Comment: Sure just check `req interface{}`

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/tree/master/logging). There is example for [zap](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/blob/master/logging/zap/payload_interceptors.go#L27-L41).